# Convert SPM modules to .xcframework

Tags: swift5, ios13, xcode12, swift-package-manager, xcframework

My iOS project is split up in several SPM modules. Now I would like to distribute some of them as .xcframework.

Is there a way to automatically create .xcframeworks out of the SPM modules? Or some (fastlane?) script I could use to create them?

Comment: Hi, you can try this repo: https://github.com/gurhub/surmagic. First, you should create a Surfile and add your desired targets. Check on the wiki page. Months ago it was a script project to create Frameworks, later I converted an XCFramework tool, I couldn't try in multiple projects, but there is a demo project. For now, has 1 known issue, init not working as expected but you can create Surfile from the template easily actually. If you find an issue please feel free to create an issue. Hope it'll work on your scenario.